# Get blocks of text with four lines each from a text file

Tags: python, list, text, random, python-3.x

I am trying to create a quiz. In a text file, I have blocks consisting of subject, question, answer and an empty space (on that order). Each line represents one of those items:

> Histology What do megakaryocytes originate? Platelets.
>
> Physiology Which physiological process does not occur in Glanzmann's
>   thrombasthenia? Platelet aggregation.
>
> Histology When in the erythropoietic process does the cell lose its
>   nucleus? When in the ortochromatophilic stage.
>
> Physiology Which phase of hemostasis features the action of
>   coagulation factors? Secondary hemostasis.
>
> Physiology What characterizes hemarthrosis? Blood in joint spaces.
>
> Physiology Beyond being in circulation, a portion of platelets is also
>   stored. Where? The spleen.
>
> Physiology Which of the platelet zones includes the submembranous
>   region? Peripheral zone.

I have successfully coded a program that shows the user the question and then reveals the answer when the user says so. However, I wanted to display the questions randomly. What I used to display them sequentially was inspired by Michael Dawson's book "Python programming for the absolute beginner". I followed the structure the author showed closely and it works. The code is:

```
#File opening function. Receives a file name, a mode and returns the opened file.
def open_file(file_name, mode):
    try:
        file = open(file_name, mode)
    except:
        print("An error has ocurred. Please make sure that the file is in the correct location.")
        input("Press enter to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return file

#Next line function. Receives a file and returns the read line.
def next_line(file):
    line = file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

#Next block function. Receives a file and returns the next block (set of three lines comprising subject, question and answer.
def next_block(file):
    subject = next_line(file)
    question = next_line(file)
    answer = next_line(file)
    empty = next_line(file)
    return subject, question, answer, empty

#Welcome function. Introduces the user into the quizz, explaining its mechanics.
def welcome():
    print("""
        Welcome to PITAA (Pain In The Ass Asker)!
     PITAA will ask you random questions. You can then tell it to
    reveal the correct answer. It does not evaluate your choice,
    so you must see how many you got right by yourself.
    """)

def main():
    welcome()
    file = open_file("quizz.txt", "r")
    store = open_file("store.bat", "w")
    subject, question, answer, empty = next_block(file)
    while subject:
        print("\n")
        print("Subject: ", subject)
        print("Question: ", question)
        input("Press enter to reveal answer")
        print("Answer: ", answer)
        print("\n")
        subject, question, answer, empty = next_block(file)
    file.close()
    print("\nQuizz over! Have a nice day!")

#Running the program
main()
input("Press the enter key to exit.")
```

How can I group blocks of 4 lines and then randomize them? It would be even better if I could filter them by subject and question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    try:
        file = open(file_name, mode)
    except:
        print("An error has ocurred. Please make sure that the file is in the correct location.")
        input("Press enter to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return file

def replace_linebreaks(value):
    value.replace("/", "\n")

def main():
    welcome()
#    store = open_file("store.bat", "w")
    file = open_file("quizz.txt", "r")
    questions = file.read().split('\n\n')  # if UNIX line endings
    file.close()
    random.shuffle(questions)

    for question in questions.splitlines():
        subject, question, answer, empty = map(replace_linebreaks, question)

        print("\n")
        print("Subject: ", subject)
        print("Question: ", question)
        input("Press enter to reveal answer")
        print("Answer: ", answer)
        print("\n")
        subject, question, answer, empty = next_block(file)
    print("\nQuizz over! Have a nice day!")
```

Answer (score 1):

To organize I would make a simple class or use dicts. For example:

Class implementation

```
class Quiz():

    def __init__(self, question, answer, subject):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.subject = subject
```

You can make an instance of those questions and create a subject for each of them, accessing them based on their attribute. As such:

```
q = Quiz("Question 1", "Answer 1", "Chemistry")
print(q.subject)
>>> Chemistry
```

You can append the new instance to a list and just randomize the list as such

```
import random #Look up the python docs for this as there are several methods to use

new_list = []
new_list.append(q)
random.choice(new_list) #returns a random object in the list
```

You can also do this with nested dictionaries and drill down based on the 'subject'

```
new_dict = {'subject': {'question': 'this is the question', 
                        'answer': 'This is the answer'}}
```

But I feel its easier to organize by creating your own class.

Hope that helps a little...